# If f(x) is irreducible, is x + (f(x)) always a generator of the quotient field?

Tags: finite-fields

If $f(x)\in F[x]$ is irreducible, $F$ is a finite field, then the quotient $F[x]/(f(x))$ is a field.

Is $x + (f(x))$ always a generator of this field? Meaning powers of it always generate the whole field except $0$. Does it hold or not?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: I have an impression that x powers can generate the multiplicative group of field for smaller sizes, but not sure if it holds for arbitrary sizes.

Comment: Do you mean, say, F is a finite field? If $F=\mathbb R$ then the quotient field has the cardinality of continuum, while powers can be at most countable.

Comment: Yes, only consider finite field for this question.

Comment: Because in crypto only finite field is used. That's why I tagged with "finite-fields".

Comment: @JamesLee Your problem can be restated as, whether a generator $\alpha$ of a finite field extension $K/F$ (an element such that $K=F(\alpha)$) is a generator of the multiplicative group of $K$. This is not true in general, but the converse holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not always true. Consider the quotient field
$$
\Bbb F_3[x]/(x^2+1).
$$
Here $x$ is not a generator of the nonzero elements in this field.

Comment: Is it always true for finite fields with characteristic 2 ?

Comment: @JamesLee No, but then the smallest example is the quartic $f(x)=x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$. With that choice the powers of the coset $x+\langle f(x)\rangle$ start repeating after the fifth.